# Curiosity with surreal numbers

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, surreal-numbers

I'm a high school student who is interested in surreal numbers and studying it by myself. Suddenly a weird idea popped in my mind. For example, can we define an event $A$ that has $P(A)=\frac1{\omega}$? Or can we construct a geometric system with surreal numbers?

Comment: Traditional probability has real values between $0$ and $1$.  You can try using other values and see what works: yes surreal numbers, but also negative numbers, complex numbers.  But unless it is useful for something, it will not be of much interest.

Comment: I'm sorry i should delete this question

Comment: @YongRyu, you can also flag a moderator to migrate the question to math.stackexchange, if you prefer. If I may add a suggestion, please try to add a little bit of background and more details to the question if you repost it on math.stackexchange.

Comment: @Ricardo Andrade, thanks for your suggestion. I should repost it later because i'm in korea(night) and i have poor english skills.

Comment: Already done (not with the surreals) http://mathoverflow.net/questions/107945/nonstandard-analysis-in-probability-theory

Comment: Roll a ω sided dice ω times. You win if you roll a 1. Whats your chance of winning to the nearest percent?

Comment: There are strange surreal numbers that do not involve infinitesimals or infinities, such as there being infinite values for each equivalent real, values that are both greater than 1 and less than -1, at least 1 value that it between 0 and 0, and at least one value without an equivalent real. You could try probability involving those values.

Comment: @alan2here 100%? (Provided the $\omega$ sided dice actually includes a 1 eg. is the set of natural numbers)

Comment: @alan2here Your comment could be correct or not, depending on how you define the surreals! Without restrictions on the left and right sets, you get the numbers you mention, e.g. *={0|0}. It is common, however, to require that no element in the right set is smaller than or equal to any member of the left set, which exclude such "numbers". You could work without them, but these restrictions are needed to get many nice properties people like, such as an order of the elements. See for instance https://www.m-a.org.uk/resources/downloads/4H-Jim-Simons-Meet-the-surreal-numbers.pdf

Answer (score 6):

For probability, yes $0<1/\omega<1$, but the problem is that there isn't a good theory of surreal integration, so you can't handle things like integrating a [probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). That just leaves you with things like "this super-unfair coin has probability $1/\omega$ of landing on heads and probability $1-1/\omega$ of landing on tails", which isn't particularly interesting, but I suppose causes no logical problems.

What do you mean by "geometric system"? How about the following?: I define the "surreal plane" to be ordered pairs of surreals. Then I can talk about the triangle with vertices $(1/\omega,3)$, $(\sqrt{\omega},-\omega^2)$, and $(0,0)$. It has "area" $(\omega+3\sqrt{\omega})/2$ by [the shoelace theorem](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Shoelace_Theorem). Again, the lack of surreal integration limits what one can do with this idea.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer! Has inspired me in my work w/ surreal geometry. Just wanted to say thanks (:

Comment: Re: super-unfair coin, it [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) lands on tails - my type of coin!

Comment: I can't *precisely* explain how [ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) & [surreal probability](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5429) are connected. Can you see the correlation?

Comment: @meowzz I think they're far enough away that it's like Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon. That surreal probability paper involves surreal numbers. Surreal numbers [contain and are like](https://mathoverflow.net/a/91654/28209) Robinson's [hyperreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number). Hyperreals are often defined by an [ultraproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct). Ultraproducts depend on an [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter).

Comment: "six degrees of math" is my new favorite game! (see also: [erdos number](https://curiosity.com/topics/paul-erdos-was-the-eccentric-nomadic-prolific-mathematical-prodigy-youve-never-heard-of-curiosity/))