# Is there any theory looking at infinitesimal probabilities as surreal numbers??

Tags: probability-distributions, infinitesimals, surreal-numbers

After getting a basic introduction to surreal numbers, it occurred to me that perhaps infinitesimal probabilities, such as the probability of draws from a continuous distribution, might be expressible as surreal numbers.

I'm interested in this idea but not able to find others having explored it previously. Is there any theory exploring this? Or alternately an explanation why this would not make sense as exploration?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A friend of mine was asking me a very similar question, about whether infinitesimals can be used to represent probabilities of events that are possible but are traditionally assigned probability zero. I essentially told him I don't know. I would guess that surreal numbers aren't the best kind of infinitesimals to use for this. You might try googling infinitesimal measure theory.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661053/curiosity-with-surreal-numbers

Comment: Thank you, this linked 661053 question has some papers and links touching on what I was trying to get out of this question, so I'll close it.  I basically wanted to see any paper(s) or articles, sorry if that was too vaguely phrased.   Appreciate the response @subrosar.

Comment: Sure! Also, I don't know know if you'll find this relevant, but it seems like it might be: http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/16825/1/Infinitesimal%20atomism_penultimate.pdf